# How can I escape null check when call a API?

Tags: java, spring, spring-restcontroller

When I write RestController in Spring, all time I check whether object is null or not. How can I escape this check?

In below example, there is null check and later return notFound or Http status 404. So I don't want to check it all time.

```
  @GetMapping(path = "/api/member/{member-id}")
  public ResponseEntity<Member> getMemberById(@PathVariable(name="member-id", required=true) final Long memberId) {
    final Member member = memberService.findById(memberId);
    if (member != null) {
      return ResponseEntity.ok(member);
    }
    return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
  }
```

Comment: You could put these four lines into a (generic) method. Then call the method instead of the if statement.

Comment: Spring boot version??

Comment: Version: 2.0.2.RELEASE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although you cannot avoid the null-check itself, you can move it out of the Controller into the service (also, use `Optional`). If you are looking for a general strategy to handle negative response scenarios, I'd suggest using Spring's `RestControllerAdvice` annotation that will enable global exception handling for all your APIs:

Let's first move the check to the service and raise a custom exception `MemberNotFoundException` in case no record is found.

*DefaultMemberService.java*

```
public Member findById(final String memberId) {
  Optional<Member> member = memberRepository.findById(memberId);
  return member.orElseThrow(() -> new MemberNotFoundException("Invalid member Id"));
}
```

In the Controller, just make a call to the service method, and return the response.

*MemberController.java*

```
@GetMapping(path = "/api/member/{member-id}")
public ResponseEntity<Member> getMemberById(@PathVariable(name="member-id", required=true) final Long memberId) {

  return ResponseEntity.ok().body(memberService.findById(memberId));
}
```

As you can see, we're not handling the exception explicitly. Instead we'll let `RestControllerAdvice` do it for us by mapping the exception class to the response (error message, response code):

*ExceptionHandlerControllerAdvice.java*

```
@RestControllerAdvice
public final class ExceptionHandlerControllerAdvice {

  @ExceptionHandler({ MemberNotFoundException.class })
  @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
  ResponseEntity<ErrorDto> handleRecordNotFound(MemberNotFoundException ex) {
    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
        .body(new ErrorDto(ex.getMessage));
  }
}
```

where, `ErrorDto` (simplified) is:

```
public class ErrorDto {
  private String message;

  public ErrorDto(String msg) { this.message = msg; }

  public String getMessage() { return this.message; }
}
```

Ref: [RestControllerAdvice](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RestControllerAdvice.html), [ExceptionHandler](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ExceptionHandler.html)

Answer (score 1):

That is perfectly fine.

Alternatively, `memberService.findById` can return an `Optional<Member>` instead, then you can do something like:

```
memberService.findById(memberId)
  .map(it -> ResponseEntity.ok(member).build())
  .orElse(ResponseEntity.notFound().build());
```

You can also "encode" the return type in an exception type, and whenever you are searching for the requested resource at the database tier/layer, if not present you can throw that exception that gets translated into an `HTTP Not Found` downstream – in some exception handler. In that case you wouldn't need to worry about the different return types in the controller – but all that magic also comes with some drawbacks, for instance, it wouldn't be quite clear (for newcomers) what's going on just by inspecting the code, unless you've been working on it for a while.

Moreover, if you are looking not to repeat the same `null` check, you can wrap that in a generic/common method.